# Drawing rotated bitmap with anti alias

Tags: android, paint, antialiasing

I tried to paint a rotated bitmap with anti alias turned on, but it still has alias and it's not smooth, any help?

I did as following:

```
final Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
p.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
canvas.drawBitmap(compass, -compass.getWidth()/2,-compass.getHeight()/2,p);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Paint.setAntiAlias()` is for text.

You want `p.setFilterBitmap(true)`;.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're rotating without a canvas (with `createBitmap`), set filter to `true`.

Example:

```
private static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap srcImage, float angle) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcImage, 0, 0, srcImage.getWidth(), srcImage.getHeight(), matrix, true/*set true for anti-alias*/);
    srcImage.recycle(); // discard original image

    return rotated;
}
```