# Bitmap not drawn anti-aliased

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have a custom `View` that always draws a `Bitmap` at a certain rotation. I overwrite the `onDraw` method, rotate the `Canvas` and draw the bitmap with an anti-aliased `Paint`.

```
public RotatedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    someBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // Save and rotate canvas
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(3F, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());

    // Draw the icon
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    canvas.drawBitmap(someBitmap, 0, 0, p);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(75, 50, 225, 200), 10, 10, p);

    // All done; restore canvas
    canvas.restore();
}
```

However, I always get jagged edges on the Bitmap. Note that the roudned rectangle gets nicely anti-aliased edges. Also, when I apply `p.setFilterBitmap(true);` this works (the bitmap surface gets filtered/smoothed) correctly. Am I missing something?

[image: No anti-aliasing on the photo]

Here's a minimal Android project with isolated example of one screen that shows the View that draws the non-anti-aliased Bitmap, loaded from a resource: https://bitbucket.org/erickok/antialiastest

**UPDATE:** I have also tried the following:

```
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setFilterBitmap(true);
    p.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(someBitmap, 0, 0, p);
```

But this doesn't help as `setFilterBitmap` filters the surface; it does not anti-alias the edges. Also, `setAntiAlias` does the same as directly setting the flag in the `Paint` constructor. If in doubt, please try my minimal test project. Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found why I did not get any anti-aliasing: hardware acceleration. After I (by pure accident) tested on my Nexus One it suddenly worked, while my Nexus 7 didn't. Turns out that the `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` does nothing when the `Canvas` is drawn using the hardware acceleration. With that insight I found [Romain Guy's answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730249/canvas-antialiasing-with-hardware-acceleration-android-api-11-and-later) which answers my question.

Solutions seem to be: adding a transparent border to every bitmap (manually or on the fly) or 'do something with shaders'. Neither are very appealing to me. Instead I [disabled hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) on my custom view using the `setLayerType` method. Note that this is available since API level 11, but (not by accident) you won't have to deal with hardware acceleration before any way. So I have added, in the view constructor:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```

I've updated the above referenced open-source project on BitBucket for those interested.

Answer (score 22):

Use  setFilterBitmap(true).

```
paint_object.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

it works for me too.. 
I got it from this question

[Drawing rotated bitmap with anti alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926622/drawing-rotated-bitmap-with-anti-alias)

set both the **AntiAlias** flag and **FilterBitmap** flag to true, they together shall make bitmap's edges smooth, I have tested it on Samsung Galaxy Ace , android 2.2    ...

My Testing Code is

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setAntiAlias(true);
p.setFilterBitmap(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(someBitmap, new Matrix(), p);
```

Comment: Sorry, but no. The filtering of a bitmap smooths out the content surface of an image. It does not ant-alias the edges. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: `setFilterBitmap()` in combination with `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` actually works very well for me. With the software layer alone I had still some artifacts.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I did this, but may be it likes you did :

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Just try.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's equal to what I did unfortunately, so it has the same effect (or rather, no effect on the jagged edges).

Answer (score 4):

I tested the previous suggestions and they do work for me. Maybe the issues is in your bitmap ? Maybe in your device? Here is a code that creates the bitmap inline. Check if this example works for you.

```
public class BitmapRotateActivity extends Activity { 

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));
  }
  class MyView extends View {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    public MyView(Context context) {
      super(context);

      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(160, 160, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
      Paint p = new Paint();
      p.setColor(Color.RED);
      p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
      Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
      c.drawRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), p);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      Paint pbg = new Paint();
      pbg.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
      pbg.setColor(0xffe0e0ff);
      canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), pbg);

      Paint p = new Paint();
      p.setAntiAlias(true);
      p.setFilterBitmap(true);

      canvas.save();
      canvas.rotate(3F, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
      canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 30, 30, p);
      canvas.restore();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer didn't directly answer my question, the remark 'Maybe in your device?' (and accidentily testing on my Nexus One) put me on the right path, so I'll award you the bounty. Thanks for (all) your time!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and tried all of these fixes. What finally worked is globally disabling hardware acceleration in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <application
       android:hardwareAccelerated="false" 
  ...
 >
```

and then disabling inSampleSize when I loaded my image bitmap, so that (I presume) the image would load at a high enough quality to avoid any zigzags, and then, for my actual ImageView, using the above advice: setting the layer type to View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, with a paint object with the filter bitmap set to true (as above) and anti-aliasing on.

Comment: as @eric-kok stated: disabling it for the customview is enough... you probaly wont slow down the entire app