# How to get smooth pendulum swing animation on canvas in android live wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation

I am trying to get pendulum swing animation for a image(bitmap) on canvas. I tried this code, but I want this animation to be smoother, e.g. while reaching the end, it's getting bumped to back.

```
if(angle>=SWING_MAX){
  direction = -1;
} else if(angle<=-SWING_MAX){
  direction = 1;
}

angle = angle+direction;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

float px = canvas.getWidth()/2;

float py = 0;

matrix.postTranslate(-pendulum_bitmap.getWidth()/2, 0);

matrix.postRotate(angle);

matrix.postTranslate(px, py);

canvas.drawBitmap(pendulum_bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

> How to get smooth pendulum swing animation? please suggest any other solutions to rotate bitmap

**like this speed should be increased and decreased.**

[image: output like this]

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14459129/321697

Comment: yes @kcoppock that link helped me to avoid bitmap getting pixelated..I want smoother animations..

Comment: did anyone find solution for this.....

Comment: I want solution as in picture.....please help me.